# How to draggable element in div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a group HTML element and they are in draggable div element. So I have a range HTML element. When I want to move range, all line is dragging. I set `draggable="false"` of range element, but it does not work. (I tested in chrome browser)

```css
.draggable {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true" class="draggable">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <label>This is line</label>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" />
</div>
```

Comment: No issue in firefox.

Comment: which chrome version you're using ?.

Comment: I can confirm this is a problem on Chrome 76.0.3809.132 + Linux

Comment: chrome version is 76.0.3809.132

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could disable the drag when the user clicks on the range and enable it after.

```
input.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    e.target.parentNode.draggable = false;
});
input.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
    e.target.parentNode.draggable = true;
});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pr9ztsw7/)

Answer (score 0):

Disable/Enable "draggable" on mousedown and mouseup.

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="range"]').addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => { 
  setDraggable(event.target.parentNode, false);
});

document.querySelector('input[type="range"]').addEventListener('mouseup', (event) => { 
  setDraggable(event.target.parentNode, true);
});

const setDraggable = (e, val) => {
 if (e.parentNode) {
    setDraggable(e.parentNode, val);
  }
  
  e.draggable = val;
}
```

```css
.draggable{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true">
  <div class="draggable" draggable="true">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>This is line</label>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" id="rangeInput" />
  </div>
</div>
```